# Twitter feed on Drupal from multiple accounts

Tags: social-network

I want to add several Twitter profiles on my Drupal and create groups of them and show their tweet feeds. At the moment, I found a module which let me add only one Twitter profile. Here is an example:

- Group A: User 1, user 2, user 3
- Group B: User 4, user 5
- Group C: User 6, user 7, user 8, user 9

The create blocks (probably with Views?) and show all the tweets from each group. Another problem, I had with the module I have is that it needs the user to authorize his profile to get his tweets.

Is there any other way to do it without ask from user to authorize and with multiple profiles feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [twitter module](https://www.drupal.org/project/twitter) allows you to get the tweets from various accounts and display them  via views.

So you can have a view for your first 3 users and then another one for the other two and so on...

Now, you will have to provide an authenticated account  via the twitter apps api. But then you'll be able to pull tweets from other non authenticated accounts.